# MongoDB - find() with 5 filters and conditions gives different results than no conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I'm wrote and tested a query to retrieve the documents and it works just fine it gets exactly what I asked for and when I take out each of the filters it retrieves the corrent documents. Now instead of manually commenting each filter I want to base it on the index as it goes down, so at `index = 4` it should use all filters and at `index = 3` it should use one less filter until at `index = 0` where it should just get the documents.

The code that works just fine:

```
    users = await User.find({
      $and: ignoreUsers.map((id) => {
        return { _id: { $ne: new ObjectId(id) } };
      }),
      objectives: { $in: objectives },
      ranking: ranking,
      expLevel: { $gte: expLevel - 1, $lte: expLevel + 1 },
      industries: { $in: industries },
      "skills.self": { $in: skills },
      interests: { $in: interests },
    });
```

This produces 1 document which is correct, however when I add the if conditions it produces 5 documents which is not corrent. The `ranking.<variable>` are numbers 1-4 so if the `index = 4` then all the if conditions should be true right? but none of them are being executed. only the objectives and ranking filters work, the whole `$expr` conditions are being ignored

```
        let index = 4;

        // supposed to be in while loop but testing just once does not produce just the 1 document it's supposed to

        const fetchCondUsers = await User.find({
          $and: ignoreUsers.map((id) => {
            return { _id: { $ne: new ObjectId(id) } };
          }),
          objectives: { $in: objectives },
          
          $expr: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [index, 0] },
              then: {
                ranking: ranking,
              },
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [index, ranking.expLevel] },
              then: {
                $and: [
                  { $gte: ["$expLevel", expLevel - 1] },
                  { $lte: ["$expLevel", expLevel + 1] },
                ],
              },
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [index, ranking.industry] },
              then: {
                industries: { $in: ["$industries", industries] },
              },
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [index, ranking.skills] },
              then: {
                skills: { $in: ["$skills", skills] },
              },
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
            $cond: {
              if: { $gte: [index, ranking.interests] },
              then: {
                interests: { $in: ["$interests", interests] },
              },
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
          },
        }).limit(limit);
```

Ideally this is what I'm trying to do

```
      users = await User.find({
        $and: ignoreUsers.map((id) => {
          return { _id: { $ne: new ObjectId(id) } };
        }),
        objectives: { $in: objectives },
        if (index === 0) ranking: ranking,
        if (index === 1) expLevel: { $gte: expLevel - 1, $lte: expLevel + 1 },
        if (index === 2) industries: { $in: industries },
        if (index === 3) "skills.self": { $in: skills },
        if (index === 4) interests: { $in: interests },
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after staring in to the abyss I realized javascript........ AN OBJECT IS BEING PASSED IN TO THE `find()`... So I simply just took out the object in to its own variable and broke it down like so:

```
      while (users.length < limit) {
        const query = {
          $and: ignoreUserObjectIDs.map((oID) => {
            return { _id: { $ne: oID } };
          }),
          objectives: { $in: objectives },
        };

        if (index >= 0) {
          query["ranking"] = ranking;
        }
        if (index >= ranking.expLevel) {
          query["expLevel"] = { $gte: expLevel - 1, $lte: expLevel + 1 };
        }
        if (index >= ranking.industry) {
          query["industries"] = { $in: industries };
        }
        if (index >= ranking.skills) {
          query["skills.self"] = { $in: skills };
        }
        if (index >= ranking.interests) {
          query["interests"] = { $in: interests };
        }

        const fetchCondUsers = await User.find(query).limit(
          limit - users.length
        );

        users = users.concat(fetchCondUsers);
        ignoreUserObjectIDs = ignoreUserObjectIDs.concat(
          fetchCondUsers.map((user) => {
            return new ObjectId(user.id);
          })
        );

        if (index === 0) break;
        index--;
      }
```

In my defence I'm working on 3 different projects in three different languages so I tend to forget about the simple things... Anyways, if anyone else had similar issues, here you go!